# Python dict.keys to list results in duplicates

Tags: python, list, key

I have a dictionary and using `.keys()` to convert into a list of keys then lower case the keys and sort the list, like this:

```
dictionary = list()
# covert all to lower case
for word in self._dict.keys():
  dictionary.append(word.lower())
dictionary.sort()
print dictionary[:5]
```

prints `[u'a', u'a', u'aa', u'aa', u'aaa']`

Why elements are duplicated?

UPDATE: stupid me, didn't think of there might be lower case letters in the original dictionary... pure embarrassment

Comment: you shouldn't use the name `dictionary` for a list...

Comment: Your code works. The bug should be in `_dict`. Can you post how it looks like?

Comment: @JBernardo I agree, but in this case I am building a spelling dictionary list so that's why I named it "dictionary" LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you've converted the keys to lower case. For example:

```
'AAA'.lower() == 'aaa'
True
'Aa'.lower() == 'aA'.lower()
True
```

So, if you had a class defined like this:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None
        self.A = None
        self.aA = None
        self.Aa = None
        self.AAA = None
        self.aAa = None
```

And then an instance of it:

```
>>> c = C()
>>> c.__dict__
{'a': None, 'A': None, 'aA': None, 'AAA': None, 'Aa': None, 'aAa': None}
>>> c.__dict__.keys()
['a', 'A', 'aA', 'AAA', 'Aa', 'aAa']
```

Converting the keys to lower case results in duplicates:

```
>>> sorted(key.lower() for key in c.__dict__.keys())
['a', 'a', 'aa', 'aa', 'aaa', 'aaa']
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are case sensitive:

```
>>> 'AA' == 'aa'
False
```

Dictionary keys are also case-sensitive, so converting them all to lowercase might give you duplicates. To get rid of the duplicates, use a `set` object:

```
>>> list(set(['AAA', 'aaa', 'AAA', 'aaa']))
['aaa', 'AAA']
```

Comment: yes, for the life of me I didn't realise there could be lower case keys coming from the source when I created the dict variable... pure embarrassment

Answer (score 0):

If, for example, one of the keys is `u'A'` and another of the keys is `u'a'`, then you'll get `u'a'` from the first and `u'a'` from the second.